# Subclipse API from a command line java application

Tags: subclipse

I am trying to create a command line application tool that will download a project from the SVN database.

I have written the code in java. I have called a method that is responsible to open the specified database with the give user credentials.
Here, I need SVNProviderPlugin instance to get the SVNClientManager, Repositories and all other attributes.

But, for Non-IDE appliaction the SVNProviderPlugin instance is null.

I want to know how to retrieve the SVNClientManager in a java command line application using Subclipse APIs?

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to try to use Subclipse for this.  Subclipse provides an API layer called SVNClientAdapter that is a separate and can be used in any Java app.  You might use that but we do not easily package it.

I would consider just using JavaHL or SVNKit, which are the two different SVN API implementation that SVNClientAdapter serves as a wrapper for.  IOW, as long as you can control the deployment, just use one of those directly.

Or, if all you need to is simple checkout, why not just run the SVN Command line directly from Java?  I wrote a SVN Benchmark tool in Java that just uses the command line.  It is so easy to do why not?  The only reason to use JavaHL or SVNKit is if you really need deep info you could not easily get out of the command line tool.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Mark.                                          
Actually, We have developed a RCP product using eclipse.Here,we worte java code to access SVN APIs.We have used code like - 
"SVNProviderPlugin provider = SVNProviderPlugin.getPlugin();
ISVNClientAdapter svnClient=provider.getSVNClientManager().getSVNClient();"                                           
Now,we want to reuse our code for our Command line tool with some minor changes.That's why we need get the SVNClientManager. But,SVNProviderPlugin instance is null in cmd line application. So,we want some other alternatives.

Comment: If you are not doing this already, I would probably build your command line app as a headless Eclipse app so you could run it via the eclipsec console application.  This would give you the Eclipse framework and plugin infrastructure.  Otherwise, you need to write to the SVN API directly.